# java.lang.Exception.file not created properly

Tags: java

I have written the following code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
public class Steerable {
    public static byte[] aReinclude = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105,
49, 45, 50, 51, 52};
    public static long mCopatron(String name)
        throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        int k;
        byte[] c = new byte[1126];
        long d = 0;
        try {
            String path =
                "C:\\Users\\KingOfTheFeed\\Desktop\\java_programming\\exercises\\";
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(path + name);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1126; i++) {
                k = (int) Math.random() * 9;
                c[i] = aReinclude[k];
                if (i < 645) {
                    d = d + c[i];
                }
            }
            f.write(c);
            f.close();
            return d;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error printing byte");
        } finally {
            return d;
        }

    }

    public static int[] mGentrice(String name1)
        throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        String path =
            "C:\\Users\\KingOfTheFeed\\Desktop\\java_programming\\exercises\\";
        FileInputStream c = new FileInputStream(path + name1);
        int k = 0;
        int[] pin = new int[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            pin[i] = 0;
        }
        byte[] b = new byte[c.available()];
        pin[0] = c.available();
        c.read(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < pin[0]; i++) {
            k = b[i];
            switch(k) {
                case 97:
                    pin[1]++;
                    break;
                case 98:
                    pin[2]++;
                    break;
                case 99:
                    pin[3]++;
                    break;
                case 100:
                    pin[4]++;
                    break;
                case 101:
                    pin[5]++;
                    break;
                case 102:
                    pin[6]++;
                    break;
                case 103:
                    pin[7]++;
                    break;
                case 104:
                     pin[8]++;
                     break;
                case 105:
                     pin[9]++;
                     break;
                case 49:
                     pin[10]++;
                     break;
                case 45:
                     pin[11]++;
                     break;
                case 50:
                     pin[12]++;
                     break;
                case 51:
                     pin[13]++;
                     break;
                case 52:
                     pin[14]++;
                     break;
            }
        }
        return pin;
    }
}
```

It has no compillation errors but jarpeb shows this message :
Wrong : java.lang.Exception: was not created properly file the mCopatron method (wrong size, should be 1126 bytes)

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure created the file with the right extention like file.txt and the right path?

Comment: Please edit your post and add the full stack trace generated when running your program.

Comment: Well, I changed the path and now jarpeb shows this message: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pin is an array of size 8

```
int[] pin = new int[8];
```

So you can only access pin[0] to pin[7]. This line throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
pin[8]++;
```