# File management and sizes

Tags: java

I have a task in Java generated from an exercise randomizer application and it's quite a pain. The instructions are:

> Write a class named Stearyl with a public identifier which must
>   contain two public, static methods named mAmatorial and mSamanid. The
>   first method mAmatorial should accept as an argument string (String).
>   The string will contain the name of the file to be created. Caution:
>   you have to set the path of the location of the file This file should
>   have the following characteristics:
>
> Size: 1077 bytes
>
> List of allowed bytes: byte [] aRetooth = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102,
>   103, 104, 105}. The list of allowed bytes should be set as static
>   public feature of class Stearyl named aRetooth. File data must be
>   random and be Evenly divisible. (All the bytes have about the same
>   number of appearances) .
>
> The method mAmatorial should return a variable type long containing
>   the sum of the first 500 bytes. The second method mSamanid must accept
>   as argument one String (String) which will contain the name of a file.
>   The file is read into memory ( set the path as above) and for this the
>   following metrics will be recorded :
>
> Size
>
> Number of occurrences of every byte included the table defined in
>   aRetooth table. The data should be returned as an array of integers
>   (int) from mSamanid. In position 1 of this table (eg a [0]) will be
>   the size of the file and in the remaining there will be the number of
>   occurrences for each byte (eg in position 2 the number of occurrences
>   of the first byte and so on ) .

When I have it to check task it says:

```
java.lang.Exception: File was not made correctly in method mAmatorial (wrong size, it should be 1077 bytes)
```

Do you know where the error is? This is an excercise from a java excercise randomizer. That means the generator has the main and u post the methods so it can check your answers. Maybe u can use sth like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Stearyl sl=new Stearyl();
    long a=sl.mAmatorial("C:\Users\***\Desktop\java_programming_2\exercises\temp.txt");
        System.out.println(a);
    int f[]=sl.mSamanid("C:\Users\***\Desktop\java_programming_2\exercises\temp.txt");
    for (int i=0;i<f.length;i++){
        System.out.println(f[i]);
    }

}
```

My code is:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

public class Stearyl{
    public static int fileSize=1077;
    public static byte[] aRetooth = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105};

public static long mAmatorial(String filename){
    Random random=new Random();
        try {

    File file1=new File(filename);
    boolean success = file1.createNewFile();

        if (!success){
            file1.delete();
            file1.createNewFile();
        }  

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;
    long sumFirst500=0;
    try {
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
        for (int i=0;i<fileSize;i++){
            byte a=aRetooth[random.nextInt(aRetooth.length)];
            if (i<500) {
                   sumFirst500+=a;
                }
            out.write(a);
                } 

        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }


    return sumFirst500;

}
public static int[]mSamanid(String filename){
    int[]pinakas=new int[aRetooth.length+1];
    int length=0;
    byte[] bytes=null;
    try {
    File file1=new File(filename);
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file1);
        length = (int) file1.length();
        bytes = new byte[(int)length];
        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
               && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }
        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file1.getName());
        }
       is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    pinakas[0]=length;

    for (int j=0;j<aRetooth.length;j++){
            pinakas[j+1]=0;
        }
    for (int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<aRetooth.length;j++){
            if (bytes[i]==aRetooth[j]) pinakas[j+1]++;
        }
    }

    return pinakas;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854618/java-lang-exception-file-not-created-properly

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: Not an answer, but I notice that you are throwing an IOException and then catching and ignoring it.

Comment: i ve seen the above question his problem was wrong path.

Comment: Can you post the main method or data you are running the methods with? I don't get any exceptions with the code

Comment: @zatara90 edit your question instead of posting code as comment

Comment: The code is running perfectly if you call the file e.g. foo.txt, it will be stored in the root of the app and the app will run successfully.

Comment: Can u show me how? Inside the methods and not in main i mean.

Comment: I think I do not understand... I've just replaced the file paths in main to foo.txt and it worked

Comment: I mean show me how to put the paths inside the respective methods and not use the main at all.

Comment: It will not solve your problem, the code will do the same thing. You cannot get rid of the main method as it is any Java app's entry point